# how can I find D in a way that $max_D{e^T V(D)^T S V(D) e}$? And how can I find differentiation of a matrix with respect to a vector?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, convex-optimization, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality

I am trying to maximize $max_D{e^T V(D)^T S V(D) e}$ with respect to D and find out D. e is a (3n+1)*1 vector. V(D) is (3n+1)*(3n+1) matrix like: V(D) = [ I & 0 & 0 & 0 \ 0 & D & 0 & 0 \ 0 & 0 & D & 0 \ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1] where D is a n*n matrix.

The way that comes to my mind is to find out the derivative of ${f= e^T V(D)^T S V(D) e}$ with respect to D by considering  as ${B = V(D) e}$ follows using chain rule:

df/dD = df/dB * dB/dV * dV/dD = 2SB * d(Ve)/dV * dV/dD

However, I have a problem in calculating d(Ve)/dV and dV/dD. Because it is a kind of finding the derivative of a vector with respect to a matrix.

Do you think that it is a good idea to maximize f like this?
How can I find the derivative of a vector with respect to a matrix?

I would be happy if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\unvc#1{\op{Unvec}\LR{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Let's use a colon to denote the extremely useful Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
Let ${I_n,Z_n\in\R{n\times n}}$ denote the identity matrix and zero matrix,
and ${z\in\R{n}}$ the zero vector.

Use them to construct the following matrix constants
$$\eqalign{
B_1 &= \m{I_n\\Z_n\\Z_n\\z^T},\quad
  &B_2 = \m{Z_n\\I_n\\Z_n\\z^T},\quad
   B_3 = \m{Z_n\\Z_n\\I_n\\z^T},\quad
   b_4 = \m{z\\z\\z\\\o} \\\\
B_k &\in\R{m\times n},&b_4\in\R{m},\qquad m= 3n+\o \\
}$$
which allow us to write a nice algebraic expression for $V$
in terms of $D$
$$\eqalign{
V &= \;B_2\;D\;B_2^T +\; B_3\;D\;B_3^T \;\;+\; B_1B_1^T + b_4b_4^T \\
\c{dV} &\c{= B_2\:dD\:B_2^T + B_3\:dD\:B_3^T} \\
}$$
Use the Frobenius product to write a nicer expression for the objective function
$$\eqalign{
f &= e^TV^TSVe \\
 &= \trace{e^TV^TSVe} \\
 &= \trace{ee^TV^TSV} \\
 &= ee^T:V^TSV \\
}$$
Now calculate the [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables) and thence the gradient of $f$
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= ee^T:\LR{dV^TSV + V^TS\;dV} \\
 &= 2ee^T:V^TS\;dV \\
 &= 2S^TVee^T:\c{dV} \\
 &= 2S^TVee^T:\CLR{B_2\:dD\:B_2^T + B_3\:dD\:B_3^T} \\
 &= 2\LR{B_2^TS^TVee^T\:B_2 + B_3^TS^TVee^TB_3}:dD \\
\grad fD &= 2\LR{B_2^TS^TVee^T\:B_2 + B_3^TS^TVee^TB_3} \\
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero and substituting the algebraic expression for $V$ will create a big ugly *linear* system of equations of the form
$$\eqalign{
\sum_j C_jDE_j = F \\
}$$
where the $\{C_j,E_j,F\}$ matrices are various products of the
$\{B_k,ee^T,S\}$ matrices.

This system can be solved using [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)
$$\eqalign{
\vc{F}
 &= \c{\sum_j \LR{E_j^T\otimes C_j}}\vc{D} \;=\; \c{M}\,\vc{D} \\
\vc{D} &= M^{-\o} \vc{F} \qiq D = \unvc{M^{-\o} \vc{F}} \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address the problem and attempting to solve it. I appreciate your approach of modifying the matrix instructions to obtain the value of $dV$. However, I have concerns about the definition of $f$, which is $f=e^TV^TSVe$, but you have defined as $f=V^TSV$. Furthermore, I am having trouble understanding how you arrived at the solution for $df$. Could you please provide a more detailed explanation?

Comment: @Negar I re-organized my post. Hopefully it's easier to follow.